# http POST vs GET request for getting a document sending a XML file

Tags: rest, http, get

I know for getting a data we have to use a GET request, but this time I have to send a XML document (who will not be stored) for getting the data. What are the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You need send a xml document to your end-point to get your interested data. 
As you **need** a xml doc, it has to be a POST REST end-point. (On a side note, sending any file contents as part of GET parameters is a bad design practice.)